# remove everything but the last 7 characters in a record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table that contains a full mailing address for customers. I'd like to get rid of the whole address and only keep the postal code (last 7 characters, including the space). I've searched for about and hour and can't figure it out.

`Table Name: Customers Column: MailingAddress`

So where I'd have

```
    MailingAddress: 1234 Example Street, Cityplace T1U 2V4
```

I'd just like to have remaining

```
    MailingAddress: T1U 2V4
```

Comment: Are you certain it will _always_ be 7 characters, or is it more complicated, like the last 2 groups of chars delimited by space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SUBSTR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

```
UPDATE Customers SET MailingAddress = SUBSTR(MailingAddress, -7, 7)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or instead of `SUBSTR()`, use the slightly simpler [`RIGHT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) to retrieve the *n* right-most characters of the expression.

```
UPDATE Customers SET MailingAddress = RIGHT(MailingAddress, 7)
```

*...because I can personally never remember the order of arguments to `SUBSTR()` or when negative values are legal.*

Comment: This worked as well after testing both. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the documentation:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr
```